# checkbox in qgis

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

Please, help me, maybe I do something wrong?
I create form in Qt disigner for QGis table. And i made there CheckBox. Then in QGIS Properties I noted that it's a checkbox and loaded on the created form. 
But when I began to edit data and set in checkbox=true value were not put In my attribute table.
I tryed to do It in Qgis 2.14 and 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

I've not found the problem...I`ll just reinstall all  soft fnd It works ok.